# Kismet + Alfa for custom 2.420GHz frequency

Tags: ubuntu, wireless, kismet-wireless

I'm running Kismet with an Alfa awus036h on Ubuntu 12.10. Is there a way to scan the non-IEEE 2.420GHz frequency with this setup? When I try to set Kismet to monitor this non-standard frequency, it gives the following error:

```
ERROR: Failed to set channel 2420: Invalid argument
```

Standard IEEE channels work just fine. Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't. The oscillator in commercial WiFi device only generates discrete frequency values as specified by IEEE. There's no way to set frequency 2420 GHz by software, unless you design the RF front end by yourself.